# Reference a range in another separate open workbook that has special characters in the name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have a formula function in a cell that I am referencing a range of cells in another open workbook. The formula looks like this:

```
=SOMEFUNCTION([name-name_(name_name).xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A)
```

Excel seems to be complaining about the "-", "(", and ")" parts of this workbook name reference. Is there any way to use these characters in a formula reference or do I have to change the file name? I'm guessing not. There are a lot of things that depend on this specific file name so I would rather not change the file name.

Note that this works, but I can't use it:

```
=SOMEFUNCTION([name_name.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A)
```

Comment: How are you actually calling it, can you post the formula? (If the name is sensitive, just make one up, but one that shows the characters you're talking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes (aka ticks or `'`) to wrap the workbook name and worksheet name together. This forces the special characters to be treated as part of a literal string.

```
=SUM('[name-name_(name_name).xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A)
```

Tested on a reference to an open workbook literally called `name-name_(name_name).xlsx`.